Date type conversion and conditions
I'm trying to compare the dates in pandas.
I want the date entry in the dataframe to lie in the window of 10 days of the date specified in the index.
This is what I'm coding:
    placeholder = -1
    date_indices = intersections_df.index.astype(np.int64) // 10**9  
    intersections_con = pd.DataFrame(index=intersections_df.index, columns=intersections_df.columns, dtype=bool)
    intersections_df_d = intersections_df.fillna(placeholder).astype(np.int64) // 10**9 
    intersections_df_d =intersections_df_d.astype(np.int64) // 10**9 
    print(intersections_df_d)
    for stock in intersections_df_d.columns:
        for i in range(len(intersections_df_d)):
            if intersections_df_d.iloc[i][stock] != placeholder:
                intersections_con.iloc[i][stock] = (
                    intersections_df_d.iloc[i][stock] > date_indices[i]
                    and intersections_df_d.iloc[i][stock] <= date_indices[i].shift(-10)
                )
            else:
                intersections_con.iloc[i][stock] = False
    print(intersections_con)

There are NaN and NaT values in the dataframe so I try to create duplicate dataframe by replace those entries with -1.
This way my original dataframe is intact and the new one is then converted to integer data.
Date is then compared to be in the range, but the issue lien in the fact that the conversion is shown to be not supported.
Atleast this is what I understand from the error.
Can someone please help me convert the date to integer and check the condition of it lying in the required range.
Following is the error that I'm encountering:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Creating Strategy Indices\Tennis Ball Effect\projects\nifty_index\source\VCP.py", line 143, in <module>
    vcp_search()
  File "D:\Creating Strategy Indices\Tennis Ball Effect\projects\nifty_index\source\VCP.py", line 123, in vcp_search
    intersections_df_d = intersections_df.fillna(placeholder).astype(np.int64) // 10**9
  File "C:\Users\devb\Anaconda\envs\pyfinance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 6534, in astype
    new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\devb\Anaconda\envs\pyfinance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 414, in astype
    return self.apply(
  File "C:\Users\devb\Anaconda\envs\pyfinance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 354, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\devb\Anaconda\envs\pyfinance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 616, in astype
    new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Users\devb\Anaconda\envs\pyfinance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\astype.py", line 238, in astype_array_safe
    new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\devb\Anaconda\envs\pyfinance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\astype.py", line 183, in astype_array
    values = _astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\devb\Anaconda\envs\pyfinance\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\astype.py", line 134, in _astype_nansafe
    return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2017-09-07'

Thanks!

did you try pd.Timedelta(days=10).value? it will generate a new date instead of shifting the date

My aim was to use minimum functions. also comparision shall come later, but rightout my aim is to get the data into correct format so as to compare it! it is not comparable at the moment :(

the issue seems to be in the dtype of the dataframe. it seems to have both NaN and NaT data. so it is an object

Did you make sure to convert to datetime in the first place? Some general remarks, NaN is a special floating point number type element. There are no NaN in integer or datetime dtype series. NaT is a special datetime type element. Vice versa, you cannot have an NaT in an integer of float dtype series. Once you mix elements (e.g. NaN in a datetime column), the series changes dtype to 'object', which means "any data type", which means many vectorized operations won't work.
